# Fetch the Resturent detail using Google Place API in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I want to get restaurant list of another countries using Google place api.i want to pass the restaurant name and postal code and country name in Google place api to get that country restaurant data.

So how to pass the restaurant name,postcal code and country name in google place api.

I am use this code

*https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/xml?query=hotel&types=restaurant|bakery|food|meal_delivery|meal_takeaway&key=APP-KEY*

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Nope. To get place details, you have to pass the placeId. So first of all get the place using a search, and secondly get the place detail using the placeId.
You can use this library to do it easily.
https://github.com/FuerteInternational/FTGooglePlacesAPI